# Saddle Point Maximization

Tags: optimization

My question is that in general, is there a case where saddle point be the global max of a function?
I am solving a game theory question which the optimal solution is the saddle point. Can I conclude that the optimal solution is at the boundaries?

Comment: I thought saddles were by definition neither max nor min.

Comment: What game theory question?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a saddle point is

- a local min in some directions and
- a local max in other directions at the same time.

Since it is a local min in at least one direction, there are more optimal points for maximization. Ditto minimization from the other directions...

Comment: Thanks, So can we say that is is only boundary solutions?

Comment: @user3425989 if no relative extrema lie inside the region, then all candidates for the optimal solutions will come from the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misunderstanding in optimization how a saddle point may be the optimal point. The saddle point that is the optimal solution is the saddle point for the Lagrange function $L(x,u,v)$, not the saddle point for the objective function itself.